# Invoke Func without knowing its return type at compile time

Tags: c#, reflection, func

I'm trying to write something and I've hit a dead end. I have the following code :

```
public class ObjectConverter
{
    private Dictionary<Type, object> m_Conversions = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public void AddConversion<TOut>(Func<object, TOut> conversion)
    {
        m_Conversions[typeof(TOut)] = conversion;
    }

    public T Convert<T>(object value)
    {
        var conversion = (Func<object, T>) m_Conversions[typeof(T)];
        return conversion(value);
    }
}
```

It's a simplification of the real thing, but basically it allows to convert an object to any type for which we have defined a conversion.
That way you can do stuff like :

```
// Intialization
converter.AddConversion(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));

// Some other place
converter.Convert<int>("12");
```

So far so good, but where it gets complicated is I want to write a non generic verison of convert like so

```
object Convert(object value, Type type)
{
    var conversion = m_Conversions[type];
    // ???
}
```

How do I do that? I thought of doing something like :

```
object Convert(object value, Type type)
{
    var conversion = m_Conversions[type];
    var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(object), type);
    var invoke = funcType.GetMethod("Invoke");
    return invoke.Invoke(conversion, new object[] { value });
}
```

But it seems very inefficient. Can you think of a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you think its inefficient?

Comment: Because of the reflection. It's probably not so bad as it is, but I was wondering if there was a better way to go about it and turns out there was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Func` is covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465122.aspx), e.g. every `Func<object, string>` will return `object` so it can be cast to `Func<object, object>` safely. So in your case you need no reflection at all.

```
public class ObjectConverter
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> m_Conversions = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>();

    public void AddConversion<TOut>(Func<object, TOut> conversion) 
    {
        // need this to support TOut as value type. 
        m_Conversions[typeof(TOut)] = obj => conversion(obj);
    }

    public T Convert<T>(object value)
    {
        return (T) Convert(value, typeof(T));
    }

    object Convert(object value, Type type)
    {
        var conversion = m_Conversions[type];
        return conversion(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: You can only cast Func<T> to Func<object> if you have a "where T : class" constraint (which totally makes sense) so I ended  up doing what you did (wrapping Func<object, T> inside a Func<object, object>) instead of casting since I needed to support value types